# SQL Complex Counting

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I want to get all the possible `type` from a table and then `count` the rows under a `group` who has this `type`.

To better illustrate consider the following table.

#### Object (o)

```
id       name             group_id       type
-----------------------------------------------------------
1        Computer         100            A
2        Monitor          100            A
3        Chair            100            B
4        Table            100            B
5        Telephone        100            C
6        Notebook         200            D
7        Pen              200            D
8        Wire             100            E
```

What I want to get is the following result:

```
group_id    type     total
-------------------------------
100         A        2
100         B        2
100         C        1
100         D        0
100         E        1
```

The `group_id` doesn't have to be included in the result, I just wanted to let you see here that I'm using a `WHERE` clause in my query. Basically I only want the results for `group | 100` but I want the counts for all `type`.

Using my query below

```
SELECT o.group_id, o.type, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM object o
WHERE o.group_id = 100
GROUP BY o.type
```

I only get the following result:

```
group_id    type     total
-------------------------------
100         A        2
100         B        2
100         C        1
100         E        1
```

You will notice that I am missing the row for `type | D`. I also want to include that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT 100 AS group_id, 
       o.type, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN o.group_id = 100 THEN 1 END) AS total
FROM object o
GROUP BY o.type
```

This query groups by `type` and uses *conditional aggregation* so as to count  the rows under each group who have `type = 100`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Type D is not returned in the query for that ID, so it is not included in the groupings. To do this, we need to get the list of ALL Types in the table, then do the counts for your ID in the table. Something like this:

```
SELECT o_list.type, COUNT(o.id) AS total
FROM object o
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT type from object ) o_list on o_list.type = o.type
WHERE o.group_id = 100
GROUP BY o_list.type
```

Giorgos's version is, arguably, cleaner to read and will always run in one full scan of the table. Mine is more complex, but if there are indexes on group_id and type, will run on index scans and so may be significantly faster on a large data set.

And you get to see that there are always options on how to solve a problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Type isn't in group 100 I first get a distinct set of types, then join back to objects since you want 100 for type D, I always show 100 when the type doesn't exist.

```
SELECT coalesce(O.Group_ID,100) as Group_ID, T.Type, count(O.Group_ID) as Total
FROM (Select Distinct Type from object)  T
LEFT JOIN Object O
 on T.Type = O.Type
GROUP BY coalesce(O.Group_ID,100), T.Type
```